# GUI.Button how do I activate the on hover effects with code?

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I'm working on my menu, here I have a couple of classes (represented as GUI buttons) that the player can pick. I have already made them highlighted on hover and also it registers when a class is selected.

The issue I don't know how to solve is, I want the selected class to stay "hovered" after click so it remains highlighted and the player is aware he has selected that class.

```
if (GUI.Button (new Rect (Screen.width / 2 - 625, 500, 200, 30), "The Cunning", buttonStyle)) 
{
    classValgt = "1";

    // Some code here that makes the button appear as if hovered with the effects I added via my GUI style
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Only Use Hover Effect with GUI Skin or GUI Style,go through the documentation below.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-GUIStyle.html

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-GUISkin.html

In the Project Panel In Unity go to create and select GUISkin ,and make public GUIStyle type Variable in your script and pass your GUISkin on it and code like the Example Below:-

```
 public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour 
    {
        public GUIStyle style;
        void OnGUI() 
        {
            GUI.skin.label = style;
            GUILayout.Label("This is a label.");
            Debug.Log("" + GUI.skin.button.hover.textColor);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this by using two GUIStyles and a bool "selected" for each object represented for your button. Test the state of your bool before drawing the button and pass the correct style (selected/unselected) to it.

Even better if you could use [GUI.Toggle](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.Toggle.html) instead of a button (you can change the style to resemble a simple button instead of a toggle). It is way more elegant as it controls selected/unselected status automatically and uses just one style (hold state for unselected and OnHold state for selected).